# Clarification on lies incorporated

Tags: philip-k-dick

I've seen few references for the book lies incorporated online, and having read through it, I'd like some answers.

In Philip K. Dick's book lies Inc, what is Abba? Does he represent something?

When lies incorporated beams the information about the rat into Applebaum's head, information which isn't a lie, is there any significance to this?

Comment: You should ask these as separate questions. At the moment it is likely to be closed.

Comment: If you're still curious, here's a couple of liner notes. "Abba" is an Aramaic word for "Father", used by Christ during his crucifixion to cry out to God and signal his obedience.

The beaming of information reflects an experience Philip K Dick had in his own life, where he perceived God "beaming" information about his son's birth defect and medical peril into his head, with a beam of pink light emanating from a Christian woman's pendant necklace.

Comment: @ConnieMnemonic This is really interesting. Thank you :)

Comment: @tuskiomi - You're more than welcome :) Sorry to necro so much. If you're interested, I'd highly recommend exploring PKD's personal life, especially later on and during the exegesis. He came to a lot of very strange ideas and had a lot of strange experiences. Reading his work is part of what led me to become a Christian personally.